# Have the ability to present multi-part, segmented content

Tags: nodes

With a Drupal 7 website I have the following requirements. It shall have the ability to present multi-part, segmented content which includes: a table of contents, links to navigate forward and backwards through the child content items, and a link to navigate up to the table of contents.

What is a good way to implement the above requirements?

Comment: The current form of this question seems too broad. What is _content_? You'll need hierarchical relationship management; but without clarifying your question, you're unlikely to get solid answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided "contents" means "nodes" (and it usually does in the Drupal universe) this looks like the sort of application that the core [book](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/book) module is supposed to handle.

If you require functionality *beyond* what is provided by the book module, you need to expand the question.

Note than in Drupal 7, the  hierarchical relationship management, navigation links and generated table of contents may be extended to *any* node entity, just by including the node in a "book" (i.e. you no longer need to use the *book* content type to have the functionality of the book module).